# Extracting nested json keys recursively

Tags: python, json, recursion, nested

I'm trying to extract key/values from a nested JSON in order to insert values into SQL table where the keys would be column names. Here's a sample of my data:

```
json = {'inquiry_date': '2021-01-14',
 'address': {'city': 'Warsaw',
 'zip_code': '20-200',
 'country': 'Poland',
 'house_no': '22',
 'street': 'Some-Street'},
 'insert_date': '2020-12-20',
 'is_active': False}
```

and here's my function:

```
def extract(json):
    for k, v in json.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            extract(v)
        else:
            print(k, v)
```

That gives me the output of key-value pairs, but as the JSON is nested and as I don't know how many levels there are and what the keys may be, I'd like to have it shown like so:

```
inquiry_date 2021-01-14
ADDRESS city Warsaw
ADDRESS zip_code 20-200
ADDRESS country Poland
ADDRESS house_no 22
ADDRESS street Some-Street
insert_date 2020-12-20
is_active False
```

Any hints on that one?

Comment: Heads up that this does not seem to be parsing – which usually means parsing *a string* to some proper data structure. For example, parsing a JSON string to ``dict``/``list``/etc. Are you trying to get the fully qualified key for each value, e.g. ``f"address city {json['address']['city']}"``? Is there a reason why you expect ``ADDRESS city Warsaw`` when the JSON contains ``address city Warsaw``?

Comment: That's correct, I'm trying ot get a fully qualified key for each value - a full chain of key/values for every record, in this case - address city Warsaw.
And there's no reason why I need address in upper case, it may stay as it is, I capitalized it to show what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

json = {'inquiry_date': '2021-01-14',
 'address': {'city': 'Warsaw',
 'zip_code': '20-200',
 'country': 'Poland',
 'house_no': '22',
 'street': 'Some-Street'},
 'insert_date': '2020-12-20',
 'is_active': False}

def parse_json(json,parents,n):
    for k, v in json.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            parse_json(v,parents+" "+k, n+1)
        else:
            print(parents, k, v)

parse_json(json,"",0)
```

gives:

```
 inquiry_date 2021-01-14
 address city Warsaw
 address zip_code 20-200
 address country Poland
 address house_no 22
 address street Some-Street
 insert_date 2020-12-20
 is_active False
```

Comment: unfortunately address is not the key of insert_date and is_active items, that would be incorrect

Comment: Correct, I would have thought the recursion would have handled that.

Comment: I have learnt that I have to pass an immutable object, eg. a string, as parameter.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Your "json" isn't real JSON.  The single quotes should be double, False should be false.  You'll find out when trying to use the json library.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by adding additional parameter to function, works fine now:

```
def extract(json, header):
    for k, v in json.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            extract(v, header + ' ' + k)
        else:
            print(header, k, v) 

for k, v in json.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        extract(v, k)
    else:
        print(k, v)
```

Comment: As you can see in my answer, there's no need to repeat the loop twice.

Comment: oh, I didn't notice your edited answer, marked as solution, thanks!